# Laravel many to many values shown in list

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many

I have menu items, and menu categories. Categories are assigned to menu items. So a 'pizza' goes under 'dinner' for example.

In my list of menu items, im tring to show the category in the list view but i can't work out how to show the category name in my menu item list as a loop. I have no problem managing this data outside of the context of a list.

This is the index() in my menu items controller

```
public function index() {
   $lists = Menu::orderBy('position')->orderBy('page_name')->paginate( 20 );
   return view( 'auth.admin.menu.index' )
   ->with( 'title', "Menu" )
   ->with( 'lists', $lists );
}
```

Loop is . . .

```
@foreach ($lists as $list)
…
@endforeach
```

Models are

```
public function menucats() {
    return $this->belongsToMany( 'app\Menucat' )->withTimestamps();
}

public function menu() {
    return $this->belongsToMany( 'app\Menu' )->withTimestamps();
}
```

So the end result of what i am trying to achieve should look like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Menu Items (Menu)</th>
      <th>Category (Menucat)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>Pizza</td>
      <td>Dinner</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>Ice Cream</td>
      <td>Desert</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>Coffee</td>
      <td>Hot Drinks</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated per comment**

After re-reading your question I don't believe you need to update your model. If the relationship you want is that many `menucats` can belong to many `menus`.

In your controller you would do

```
public function index() {
   $lists = Menu::with('menucats')
              ->orderBy('position')
              ->orderBy('page_name')
              ->paginate( 20 );
   return view( 'auth.admin.menu.index' )
   ->with( 'title', "Menu" )
   ->with( 'lists', $lists );
}
```

Then during your loop it would be accessed like this.

```
@foreach($lists as $list)
  ...
  @foreach($list->menucats as $category)
      {{ $category->name }}
  @endforeach
  ...
@endforeach
```

**Updated again per comment**

In order to group by menucats, I would get all `menucats` with their associated `menus`.

Something like this in your controller should work. The paginate might be tricky.

```
public function index() {
   $lists = Menucats::with(['menu' => function($q){
              $q->orderBy('position')
                ->orderBy('page_name');
            ])->paginate( 20 );

   return view( 'auth.admin.menu.index' )
   ->with( 'title', "Menu" )
   ->with( 'lists', $lists );
}
```

Check out **Constraining Eager Loads** under [Querying Relations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

Comment: thanks, i wasn't aware of the with() function! Is it not possible to do this without changing the model? Is it required that i change the mode?

Comment: @cardi777 I updated my answer. After re-reading your question, it looks like you already have a many-to-many relationship defined. If this is the case, you would access the related categories as I noted.

Comment: Thanks very much, im almost there now. So i supose in this instance, it would be impossible to order by the category?

Comment: Yeah, In that case you need to query by `menucat` and get the associated `menu`.

Comment: could you show me what that would look like, as I am getting an error.

Comment: @cardi777 Updated answer again, hope this works. It might need to be adjusted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82438/discussion-between-cardi777-and-whoacowboy).